# How to replace or destroy a tab using the Firefox Add-on SDK?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I did not find anything in the Firefox Add-on SDK (Tab API) that can destroy a tab or replace it with a new tab. I can find the Tab ID, Tab URL, or other identifier. Is there any way to replace or destroy a tab?

Comment: Please put your question inside your actual question text and rephrase your question title.

Comment: I have edited my question @ nop77svk

Comment: Nope, not really. The actual question still resides in your post's title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`tab.close(callback)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#close%28callback%29).

What do you mean by replace? If you just want to change the URL, then use `tab.url = url`.

Comment: I am new to Firefox addon develoment thanks so much for your useful information  @willma

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about SDK, but you can destroy and replace one tab with another tab.

This is how to do it with non-sdk:

### How to close a tab by its "id"

```
var tabIdToClose = 'panel-3-1';

Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var DOMWindows = Services.wm.getEnumerator('navigator:browser');
while (DOMWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
    var aDOMWindow = DOMWindows.getNext();
    if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser && aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
        var tabs = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            var aTab = tabs[i];
            var aTabId = aTab.getAttribute('linkedpanel');
            console.log('tab id:', aTabId);
            if (aTabId == tabIdToClose) {
                aDOMWindow.gBrowser.removeTab(aTab);
            }
        }
    } else {
        //this window does not have any tabs
    }
}
```

### This is how to replace tab with another tab and close the first tab.

```
var tabIdToReplace = 'panel-3-248';
var tabIdToReplaceWith = 'panel-3-246'; //this tab will be closed, but its contents will be in tabIdToReplace

var aTabToReplace;
var aTabToReplaceWith;

Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var DOMWindows = Services.wm.getEnumerator('navigator:browser');
while (DOMWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
    var aDOMWindow = DOMWindows.getNext();
    if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser && aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
        var tabs = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            var aTab = tabs[i];
            var aTabId = aTab.getAttribute('linkedpanel');
            console.log('tab id:', aTabId);
            if (aTabId == tabIdToReplace) {
                aTabToReplace = aTab;
            } else if (aTabId == tabIdToReplaceWith) {
                aTabToReplaceWith = aTab;
            }
            if (aTabToReplace && aTabToReplaceWith) {
                aTabToReplaceWith.ownerDocument.defaultView.gBrowser.swapBrowsersAndCloseOther(aTabToReplace, aTabToReplaceWith);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        //this window does not have any tabs
    }
}
```

### If you just want to swap the tabs without closing either then do this

I havent completed this so the swap isn't perfect, like I have to set the iconURL and title of the tab that would have been closed: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9b335a460f53b0390336

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative answser (y) @Noitidart